# Button image sizes not changing in iPad by autolayout using iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to create button Image within iPhone and iPad bottom center but button sizes not changing iPad. Its showing iPhone sizes only. Please help me to create my scenario. I am using different button Image sizes for my Universal app.

[image]

Comment: you just want this button in the center of the view right?

Comment: not only that. Thats button image. I want to resize based on device sizes ipad and iphones@Jaimish

Comment: @android if you resize the button that image will automatically getting resize...

Comment: you placed the button at bottom that is centred now  you want to resize depend upon the device i am right?

Comment: @android i have posted my answer you can verify it ....

Answer (score 0):

1. First give aspect ratio to the button, so that as per device size it will increase the button height and width as per given ratio. Follow the screen shot to give aspect ratio.

[image]

2. Now to make button in center of the view give horizontally center in container, see in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Its came bottom but still not resizing. Showing iPhone sizes on iPad.@Jaimish

Comment: iphone above I have posted same size for iPad also showing. IPhone screen above button size is looks good but For iPad small button size looks like not good. Differnt image sizes I have in asset but ist showing same button size for all the devices.@Jaimish

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Took the above image as example:

1.i know you already done centre horizontal to view constraints.

2.add leading constraints to view.

[image]
3.add trailing constraints to view.

[image]
4.add bottom space constraints to view.

[image]
5.don't set any height and width as of now.

now just run it you will get the exact requirements.......

Hope This will help you..

Comment: Please post some screen shoot. I am new dev for autolayout.@Kishore Kumar

Comment: @android no issues i will post

Answer (score 0):

You must add constraints base on the `percentage(%)` so that button image can vary according to `device`(iPhone/iPad) `screen size`.

Constraints from StoryBoard on button

```
Step 1. Drag button and place it on its proper position.

Step 2. Now Add constraint Horizontal Center in Container.

Step 2. Now Add Bottom Pin constraint.

Step 3. Add constraint Equal Width and Equal Height.

Step 4. Now update multiplier of Equal Width constraint and Equal Height.
```

Programmatically  by using the [`KVConstraintExtensionsMaster`](https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster) that will update the constraints on iPad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* preparing View Hierarchy */
    UIButton *button = [UIButton prepareNewViewForAutoLayout];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    /* applying constraints */
    [button applyConstraintForHorizontallyCenterInSuperview];
    [button applyBottomPinConstraintToSuperviewWithPadding:defualtConstant];

    [button applyWidthConstraint:280]; // fixed width for iphone
    [button applyHeightConstrain:40]; // fixed height for iphone

    // update width constraint with proper iPad ratio
    [button updateAppliedConstraintConstantValueForIpadByAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth];

    // update height constraint with proper iPad ratio
    [button updateAppliedConstraintConstantValueForIpadByAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight];
    /*
     // update Height constraints at any specific ratio on iPad
     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [button updateAppliedConstraintConstantValueByAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight withConstantRatio:1.8];
     }
     */
}
```